# R: how to chose best interaction variable in an OLS regression?

Tags: r, regression, feature-selection

I have a simple regression setup:

$Y$ = $\alpha$ + $\beta X$ + $\gamma Z$ + $\delta XZ$ + $\epsilon$

As you can see, the variable `X` is interacted with `Z` and the interaction coefficient of interest is $\delta$

In my dataframe, I have many possible variables for Z and I would like to choose automatically the best one.

That is, in each regression $X$ is the same but pick the $Z$ whose regression R-square is highest or the one where the t-stat on $\delta$ is highest among all possible regressions.

Here is a simple example

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(10)
dataframe = data_frame(Y = runif(10), X= runif(10),  Z1=runif(10), Z2 =runif(10))

> dataframe
# A tibble: 10 x 4
            Y          X        Z1         Z2
        <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 0.50747820 0.65165567 0.8647212 0.53559704
 2 0.30676851 0.56773775 0.6153524 0.09308813
 3 0.42690767 0.11350898 0.7751099 0.16980304
 4 0.69310208 0.59592531 0.3555687 0.89983245
 5 0.08513597 0.35804998 0.4058500 0.42263761
 6 0.22543662 0.42880942 0.7066469 0.74774647
 7 0.27453052 0.05190332 0.8382877 0.82265258
 8 0.27230507 0.26417767 0.2395891 0.95465365
 9 0.61582931 0.39879073 0.7707715 0.68544451
10 0.42967153 0.83613414 0.3558977 0.50050323
```

How can I do that in R without writing crazy loops?
Thanks!

Comment: Write sane loops?

Comment: haha @Gregor, please show me how

Comment: @Gregor please see the updated question

Comment: Why are you avoiding a for loop?  This seems to call for one.

Comment: I am not sure what is the most efficient way. I want to use broom to extract the statistics in each regression.

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency - just write something hacky that works. If it takes hours, then worry about efficiency.

Comment: @Gregor do you mind posting a mock solution then? thanks!!

Comment: for loops get a bad rap; many times they are perfectly appropriate.

Comment: You probably do not want to pick a single model on this way - it is essentially certain to cause (severe) overfitting, any p-values become onvalid etc. With the same set-up you can probably do model averaging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
z_options = c("Z1", "Z2")
formula_string = paste("Y ~ X *", z_options)
model_list = list()
for(i in seq_along(formula_string)) {
    model_list[[i]] = lm(as.formula(formula_string[i]), dataframe)
}

model_glance = bind_rows(lapply(model_list, glance))
model_glance[, c(1, 2, 5, 8)]
#   r.squared adj.r.squared   p.value       AIC
# 1 0.2150010   -0.17749851 0.6677345  1.327784
# 2 0.3910735    0.08661019 0.3620319 -1.212065
```

Use whatever metric you'd like to pick the best.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to not like loops either. I'm a big fan of Hadley's `purrr` package. Clean, elegant, readable code.

Here's how to use to use it, built off of @Gregor's solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

set.seed(10)
dataframe = data_frame(
  Y = runif(10),
  X = runif(10),
  Z1 = runif(10),
  Z2 = runif(10)
)

z_options = c("Z1", "Z2")
formula_string = paste("Y ~ X *", z_options)


tibble(formula_string) %>% 
  bind_cols(
    map_df(.x = formula_string,
           .f = ~ glance(lm(as.formula(.x),
                            dataframe)))
  ) %>%
select(1:4)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#         formula_string r.squared    adj.r.squared     sigma
#         <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>             <dbl>
#   1     Y ~ X * Z1     0.2150010   -0.17749851        0.2024755
#   2     Y ~ X * Z2     0.3910735    0.08661019        0.1783283
```

Comment: extremely sweet

Comment: is it possible to combine this `purr` solution with `lm` + `coeftest`? I am interested in the output of `coeftest` actually

Comment: Yea, absolutely. What's your sample code?

Comment: also, in your original solution it is hard to actually know which model is which. how can we keep track of this? can you store the model formula in the dataframe?

Comment: Done. Here's sample code for you.

Comment: I'm going to take a counterpoint.  I'm an experienced programmer in python, R, C, javascript... I have no idea what this code does or how it works or what functions come from what packages.  A for loop is available and understandable to everyone.  It's fine to use libraries when they simplify work, or add expression to the language where expressivity is lacking, but this takes a simple thing and adds layers of unneeded abstraction.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, I suppose to each his own. My team works very heavily in the tidyverse space, so we are very well versed with the verbs it encompasses. It makes for very quick reading of such code for us.

Comment: Fair enough.  The fragmentation of the R community is a frustrating point for me.